# Power Query -- list value in native query

Tags: expression, powerquery, nativequery

im having a problem using the "in" operator in a native query, where the in argument is a list retrieved by drilling a excel column table:

```
let
   var = Number.ToText(fnFuncao("externalcode")),
   Coluna= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Pendente"]}[Content],
   #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Coluna,{{"PARAMETER", Int64.Type}, {"INTERACTION_ID", Int64.Type}, {"INTERACTION_ITEM", Int64.Type}}),
   INTERACTION_ID = #"Changed Type"[INTERACTION_ID][0],
   Source = Oracle.Database("somp", [Query="select * from ish.ticket where    interaction_id in (" & INTERACTION_ID & ") "])
in
    Source

Error:
    Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Text and List.
    Details:
    Operator=&
    Left=select * from ish.ticket where interaction_id in (
    Right=List
```

Any way to work around this ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why INTERACTION_ID is treated like a list. These two changes should fix your issue:

1. Change INTERACTION_ID to `#"Changed Type"[INTERACTION_ID]{0},`
2. Set Query to `"select * from ish.ticket where    interaction_id in (" & Number.ToText(INTERACTION_ID) & ")"`

The first change uses the list access operator {} instead of the record access operator []. The second change converts INTERACTION_ID to a Text value so that it can be added to other Text values with &.

Comment: What if my interaction_id columns has values in cells a1,b1,c1. Is there any way to include all the values in the query ?

Comment: Remove the INTERACTION_ID step and use this for the query:
`"select * from ish.ticket where interaction_id in (" & List.Accumulate(List.Skip(#"Changed Type"[INTERACTION_ID], 1), Number.ToText(#"Changed Type"[INTERACTION_ID]{0}), (state, current) => state & ", " & Number.ToText(current)) & ")"`
This loops through the column and appends commas after the first element. This will only work if you have values in your column.